# Combine "input" and "select" statement in one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

How I can get a nice view, when i want to have first an input-element and after a select statement..
It looks like this now:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <select class="selectpicker form-control">
                <option value="test">Test</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I want something like on this page the element below: https://www.bootply.com/97519
But using select-statement instead of ul..

Comment: What Exactly you want clear with your Question and where you want to use this elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to like this:

```css
.input-group-addon.select-input {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0;
}

.input-group-addon.select-input select {
  border: none;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-addon select-input">
            <select class="selectpicker form-control">
                <option value="test">Test</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It is almost looking like I want. 
I want that the "Button" of the select part is that small that it's not showing the selected content.. And when i do this, then the dropdown menu is too wide.. 
I would like to do sth like class="pulled-right". Is there something for the select-dropdown?